# How to rewrite and redirect at the same time

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Let's assume there is a example.com (working on apache) and we have a subdirectory called "sub"(example.com/sub). Is it technically possible to configure .htacess to rewrite http://example.com/sub/ to http://example.com/home/ and redirect all the traffic to it, so that any path within /home should be redirected to the same path within /sub, I have tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^sub/?$ /home/ [R,NC]
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/sub
```

But eventually I get 404 Not Found. Any ideas ?

P.S. my previous question was closed even though I received 1 answer:

```
RewriteRule /sub/$ /home/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule /index.html http://example.com/sub [R]
```

Which didn't work for me(401 forbidden).

Comment: Please clarify your question so that you give us examples of what the user will see in their browser address bar, and whether you want them redirected to a different address (which changes what they see in the address bar) or you want a silent rewrite (which points to the actual file, but does not change what the user's browser shows in the address bar). It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well I will try to clarify: I want to final user to see in browser http://example.com/home instead of http://example.com/sub and I want to redirect from http://example.com to http://example.com/home . Hope now you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To silently rewrite a visitor's request for `/home/anypath/anyfile` to the underlying path on your server of `/sub/anypath/anyfile` you can use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^home(?:/(.+))?$ /sub/$1
```

To redirect the user's browser from `/` and `/index.html` to the clean `/home` URL you can try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:$|index.html$) /home [R=permanent]
```

(For both of these rules, you'll need to add a forward slash after the `^` symbol if you're using httpd.conf. If you're using .htaccess then you don't need a slash at the start of the pattern.)

Note that you can't (easily) redirect from `/sub` to `/home` because this will create an infinite loop of redirects and rewrites. But don't worry about redirecting from `/sub` to `/home` because clean URLs are about making URLs look good in advertising literature and on relaunched web pages. If a visitor happens to visit the old "ugly" URL, it won't hurt and they'll be taken to the new clean URL as soon as they click on any new links.

Comment: Well, this worked for me partly. When a visitor enters http://example.com  he is automatically redirected to http://example.com/home  just like I wanted, but whenever he clicks on an URL , he is redirected to http://example.com/sub (instead of home). Well, anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean you want a request for /home/anypath/anyfile to be silently rewritten to /sub/anypath/anyfile ? If so, that will require a change to the RewriteRule.

Comment: I feel like I've totally confused you , sorry though . I want a request for /sub/anypath/anyfile to be rewritten to /home/anypath/anyfile

Comment: I've modified this answer so that any path within /home should be redirected to the same path within /sub, but you need to edit your own question to spell out more clearly what you need, so that visitors to this page can learn from your question and any answers the question gets.